Customizing BulmaCSS colors with CSS
After reading the documentation, I still don't understand why I can't set the primary color with CSS like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Force the light theme: -->
<html data-theme="light">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello Bulma!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@1.0.0/css/bulma.min.css">

    <style>
        :root {
            --bulma-primary: red;
            --bulma-size-medium: 0.5rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="button is-primary is-medium">Button</button>
</body>
</html>

The size modifier works, but the color remains the default one.

The backgrond color for .button is not set that way.
Bulma sets .button background-color as an hsl color:
background-color: hsl(171deg, 100%,calc(41% + 0%));

which in turn comes from the stylesheet as:
 background-color: hsl(var(--bulma-button-h),var(--bulma-button-s),calc(var(--bulma-button-background-l) + var(--bulma-button-background-l-delta)));

If you don't want to bother setting those variables to your own choice you could just set the background color yourself:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Force the light theme: -->
<html data-theme="light">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Hello Bulma!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@1.0.0/css/bulma.min.css">

  <style>
     :root {
      --bulma-primary: red;
      --bulma-size-medium: 0.5rem;
    }
    
    .button {
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="button is-primary is-medium">Button</button>
</body>

</html>



Though it might be more correct to set the hsl variables in :root (e.g. might they be used by Bulma somewhere else?).

Thanks a lot for the answer. But that was only an example. I don't want to only change the color of that button, I want to change the primary color everywhere, globally, for all components and elements.

In that case you are going to have to look at what 'primary color' actually means to you versus what it means to Bulma. In the case of a button it doesn't use its own primary-color variable so you aren't talking about the same concepts.

I've read the full documentation up until "Customization" (included), and I don't get what I'm missing. Could you please hint me at what's wrong with my understanding? In the "SASS Derived Variables" section I can see the "primary" and "link" values, for example. That means that changing those, the button "is-primary" and "is-link" should change, no?
Also, in the "Migrating to v1" it says: "you can customize Bulma with CSS only (without using Sass)", so I should be able to do this with CSS.

Bulma use HSL based color system. Because Bulma SCSS version can calculate HSL values based on your colors, so only $primary needed. whereas CSS does not have this capability, so you have to set HSL values yourself.
Try this, all elements using primary color will change
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Force the light theme: -->
<html data-theme="light">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello Bulma!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@1.0.0/css/bulma.min.css">

    <style>
        :root {
            --bulma-primary-h: 100deg;
            --bulma-size-medium: 0.5rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="button is-primary is-medium">Button</button>
</body>
</html>

You can use the browser's CSS tools to trace step by step and find the initial definition of the CSS referenced variable. By modifying its value, you can achieve a customized effect.
